# jQuery 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The title is the error I get from the following code:

```
 $(this).parent().slideUp(200, function () {
    $("#testDiv").slideUp(200);
    });
```

However the following code works fine:

```
$(this).parent().slideUp(200, function () {
$("#testDiv").html('hello');
});
```

Loaded libraries are jQuery, jQuery UI and qTip.

In IE8 I get the error as indicated. In FireFox the first slideup works then the callback causes an error and scripts stop.

The script is located in a click function handler on a div that is dynamically rendered (server-side) in an ASP.NET MVC partial view via a jQuery load().  The testDiv div is on the view itself and rendered in the original request.

Any ideas why the html() call works, but not the animation?

Comment: I'd like to see how you're calling the code after/in the $.load() statement. You may be trying to call this code on an element that has not yet been imported into the DOM.

Comment: Does the html() call actually *work*, or does it just not throw errors?

Comment: @jason: thanks, jason, I thought through this and I am not sure this is the case, but is there a way to determine the order the objects are loaded into the DOM?  The #testDiv element is created server-side and returned to the browser, along with the script to load a side bar.  The side bar contains an image, that when clicked, performs the above code.  I'm pretty sure the #testDiv is loaded as the .html() call works...

@Matchu: The html() call works, the existing innards are replaced with with the text hello and no errors are raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely has something to do with your use of .parent().
I recommend using .parents('.ClassName') and calling it by a specific class name or ID.

This will help clear up most of those issues.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree. You should never write any code like above. What if parent is empty?

Comment: Given the way the parent and child is created it is impossible for the parent to be empty for that block of code.  'Never' is a very strong pattern ;o)

The problem isn't the parent or the call to parent or the slideUp on parent.  The problem is that the slideup doesn't work on the $("#testDiv") selection.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as I agree it's the best approach and folks should go about it this way if they can. In my case, I was able to fix the problem by updating to a newer version of jQuery and using (at the time) jQuery.live() to provide the functionality I needed.